# Why does this date comparing where clause return no results?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE WEEKENDDT = (SELECT MAX(ENDDTE)FROM TABLE2)
```

This select for some reason is not returning data. Both tables have data for a specific date: 
MAX(ENDDTE) has data for 02-MAY-12 and so does WEEKENDDT -has data 02-MAY-12.

Comment: Dates have a time component. Are the two values you're comparing _exactly_ identical? My guess would be that they're not.

Comment: check ur datatype of both columns have `datetime`

Comment: `datetime` is not an Oracle data type.

Comment: This is tagged with plsql. Are you actually doing this in PL/SQL, or is it just a query you're running in sqlplus?

Comment: Or maybe just MAX(ENDDTE) returns value that differs from 02-MAY-12 and WEEKENDDT column of TABLE1 doesn't have it. Would be great to see what datatype columns in the WHERE clause have, and example of actual data in them

Comment: please improve your question, specify the datatypes and your tables content.

Comment: If they're both date columns then `table1.weekenddt != max(table.enddte)`, which is why nothing is getting returned. If you want to do it without time then João's answer is correct; otherwise there's nothing you can do. The query is returning the correct result set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can happen if the `time` part of the `date` differs.

For example, if `WEEKENDDT` in `Table1` has the value `02-09-2012 18:47`, and `MAX(ENDDTE)` of `Table2` is `02-09-2012 00:00`, they are ***not*** equal, and thus can't be compared with `=`.

If you want to truncate the `time` part, just use [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE TRUNC(WEEKENDDT) = (SELECT TRUNC(MAX(ENDDTE)) FROM TABLE2)
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd58f/2)**.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know SQL Fiddle.